WIN 11 Acer Aspire 5 laptop, fonts became thin and difficult to read
Running Windows 11 on an Acer Aspire 5 laptop model A515-43-R19L with full HD (1920 x 1080) LED backlit IPS display & AMD Radeon Vega 3 Mobile Graphics.
Looks like the laptop screen resolution changed from the default for no known reason, now the fonts are thin and difficult to read. Windows System Information says I'm in 1980x1080. Rebooting did not solve the problem, neither did a power cycle.
EDIT: ClearType is enabled.
How may I get back to the normal resolution so text is sharp again?  See example: 

This question needs a lot of work. It should have an inline screenshot or externally hosted either. The grammar is not clear so the question is confusing. 1980x1080 is on odd resolution, is that even right? Seems like a typo. Expected higher quality questions from a user that’s been around 10 years and a higher quality question normally.

What have you tried? Adjusting ClearType? Select another display font: https://www.lifewire.com/change-font-windows-11-6827640 ?

Any Restore Points in Windows that you could try to fall back on?

The screenshot was provided. See the URL in the last paragraph. Yes, I am resurrecting a low performance machine, and yes, it is 1920x1080, as you can see if you looked at reviews such as https://www.pcworld.com/article/398022/acer-aspire-5-a515-43-r19l-review.html

Solved by
Settings | search for System Properties | Advanced System Settings | Performance, Settings | re-enable Smooth edges of screen fonts
